# Adding end line marker in QPlainTextEdit

Tags: qt, qplaintextedit

I would like to add a vertical line that would mark 80 characters in `QPlainTextEdit`. I looked at docs but I couldn't see anything in docs. Do I need to paint it somehow myself?

Comment: Yes, you need to paint QFrame onto QPlainTextEdit widget.

Comment: Are the characters supposed to have fixed width?

Comment: Yes, they should have fixed width. How should paint QFrame onto a QPlainTextEdit. Could you show me some example?

Answer (score 1):

I think one possible way is to reimplement the [paintEvent](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qplaintextedit.html#paintEvent)() and draw the line using a QPainter after calling the base class implementation. The position of the line might be computed using [QFontMetrics](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qfontmetrics.html).